Problem installing QT extension on Visual Studio
I installed Visual Studio version 2013 on the system and QT version 10 and qt-vsaddin-msvc2013-2.3.2 extension.
As a result, I could not find the file that the extension wanted from inside the QT folders.
I had to install Visual Studio version 2017 and qt-vsaddin-
I tried to install msvc2017-2.10.1-rev.2, it gave an error with the following title:
Installation Failed
The installation was unable to install the extension to all the
selected products. For more information, click on the installation log
link at the bottom of the dialog.
0 This extension is not installable on any currently installed
products.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? No matter what I did, I could not delete the previous version of the extension
I couldn't find the extension from the Add Remove section of Windows, not from anywhere else
